# Laravel, 'env' in database config

Tags: php, database, laravel, sqlite

i was configuring my sqlite connection in framework laravel. While using 'php artisan migrate' command i've  got a message  that there is no connection.

I changed this two lines of my code

**`'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlite'), 
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite'))`**

to

**`'default' => 'sqlite',
'database' => database_path('database.sqlite'),`**

Now everything works fine,  but my question is **what does the ENV function do??** 
Am  i right to delete this?

Comment: Read https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration#environment-configuration.

Comment: The role of `env` is simply read the given value from `.env` file and the second parameter is the default value if the given key not found in the .env file

Comment: What you can do is set the value of `DB_CONNECTION` to `'sqlite'` in the `.env` file and use the first code

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel `env()` is the helper function, which gets the value of an environment variable or returns a default value:

Example:

```
$env = env('DB_CONNECTION');

// Return a default value if the variable doesn't exist...
$env = env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqllite');
```

To give your application a speed boost, you should cache all of your configuration files into a single file using the `php artisan config:cache`. **Which cache the env values as well, so in order to take effect of cached values changes one must have to clear it by using** `php artisan cache:clear`

Answer (score 1):

The env function gets the value of an environment variable from your `.env` file or returns a default value which is the second argument.

For more information read: [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration#environment-configuration)